# Problem performing a substitution in a multiple derivative

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a basic problem in Mathematica which has puzzled me for a while. I want to take the m'th derivative of `x*Exp[t*x]`, then evaluate this at `x=0`. But the following does not work correct. Please share your thoughts.

```
D[x*Exp[t*x], {x, m}] /. x -> 0
```

Also what does the error mean

```
General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable.
```

---

**Edit:** my previous example (`D[Exp[t*x], {x, m}] /. x -> 0`) was trivial. So I made it harder. :)
My question is: how to force it to do the derivative evaluation first, then do substitution.

Comment: Does Mathematica evaluate the derivative without the substitution?

Comment: Looks like Mathematica doesn't know how to do that derivative, so you can't force derivative evaluation

Comment: @Yaroslav: is it true? I know closed-form solution of D[Exp[x^2],{x,m}]/.x->0. Wouldn't mma also be able to do this? If so, what is the way please?

Comment: +1 It's a simple problem, but this error is one that every student of mathematica runs into.

Comment: @Simon And some of us, from time to time (not very often (*cough*)), spend some time thinking _Why that derivative is going nuts??_ ... and then remember :)

Comment: @Yaroslav: Mma does know how to do the derivative, you just have to ask it nicely (see my answer).

Comment: ok, looks like SeriesCoefficient should be used instead of D if you want derivative for fixed x and arbitrary m

Comment: As of version 13.0+, symbolic, fractional and negative derivative orders in `Derivative[n]` are supported, so you can do `FunctionExpand[D[x Exp[t x], {x, m}] /. x -> 0]`, which yields `m t^(-1 + m)`. Note that the answer `D[f[x],{x,n}]` gives may be valid only if `n` is non-negative and integer. `FractionalD` and `CaputoD` handle fractional and symbolic fractional derivatives, which are equivalent to an integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by others, (in general) Mathematica does not know how to take the derivative an arbitrary number of times, even if you specify that number is a positive integer.
This means that the `D[expr,{x,m}]` command remains unevaluated and then when you set `x->0`, it's now trying to take the derivative with respect to a constant, which yields the error message.

In general, what you want is the m'th derivative of the function evaluated at zero.
This can be written as

```
Derivative[m][Function[x,x Exp[t x]]][0]
```

or

```
Derivative[m][# Exp[t #]&][0]
```

You then get the table of coefficients

```
In[2]:= Table[%, {m, 1, 10}]
Out[2]= {1, 2 t, 3 t^2, 4 t^3, 5 t^4, 6 t^5, 7 t^6, 8 t^7, 9 t^8, 10 t^9}
```

But a little more thought shows that you really just want the m'th term in the series, so `SeriesCoefficient` does what you want:

```
In[3]:= SeriesCoefficient[x*Exp[t*x], {x, 0, m}]
Out[3]= Piecewise[{{t^(-1 + m)/(-1 + m)!, m >= 1}}, 0]
```

The final output is the general form of the m'th derivative. The `PieceWise` is not really necessary, since the expression actually holds for all non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you want the mth partial derivative of that function w.r.t. x.  The t variable suggests that it might be a second independent variable.

It's easy enough to do without Mathematica: D[Exp[t*x], {x, m}] = t^m Exp[t*x]

And if you evaluate the limit as x approaches zero, you get t^m, since lim(Exp[t*x]) = 1.  Right?

---

**Update:** Let's try it for x*exp(t*x)

the mth partial derivative w.r.t. x is easily had from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+derivative+of+x+derivative+of+x+derivative+of+x+derivative+of+x+exp%28t%2ax%29+):

t^(m-1)*exp(t*x)(t*x + m)

So if x = 0 you get m*t^(m-1).

Q.E.D.

Comment: @duffymo: please look at this new example.

Comment: I think my answer still holds.  I don't know how to ask Mathematica to do it, but I do know the math involved.  My answer stands.

Comment: @duffymo To use mathematica as a functional language, you need to be able to derivate in a functional way.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, belisarius.  Do you mean "derive" or "take a derivative"?  And I don't care about functional programming; this is about the mathematics.

Comment: @duffymo he obviously means to differentiate. Not everybody is a native english speaker. as far as the mathematics is concerned, I'd say that mathematically the question is trivial enough to make it unlikely that the question was about that and not about mma's order of evaluations.

Comment: @acl - Let the OP speak for themselves.  I'm not criticizing the language, just trying to clarify.  And I don't believe it has anything to do with functional programming.  Doing this at Wolfram Alpha, which also developed Mathematica, might offer a clue.  There's no way to specify taking m derivatives.  I did successive "derivative of" and noted the pattern.  Perhaps that's a hint.

Comment: @duffymo actually D[f[x],{x,m}] specifies taking m partial derivatives of f[x] wrt x... The point of the question is that D[Exp[t*x],{x,m}] is not evaluated despite the fact that it is trivial for positive integer m, and when the substitution is made in the unevaluated form, it becomes D[Exp[t*0],{0,m}] which results in an error. This does not happen with eg D[f[x], {x, m}] /. x -> 0, for obvious reasons (once you execute it). Anyway this subdiscussion does not seem to have much of a point...

Comment: "Anyway this subdiscussion does not seem to have much of a point..." - yet still you persist.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your update, it's clear what's happening here. Mathematica doesn't actually calculate the derivative; you then replace `x` with `0`, and it ends up looking at this:

```
D[Exp[t*0],{0,m}]
```

which obviously is going to run into problems, since 0 isn't a variable.

Comment: so how to force it to do derivative evaluation first, then substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what is happening with a little more detail:

When you write:

```
D[Sin[x], {x, 1}]
```

you get an **expression** in with **x** in it

```
Cos[x]
```

That is because the **x** in the {x,1} part matches the **x** in the Sin[x] part, and so Mma *understands* that you want to make the derivative for that symbol.
But this **x**, does NOT act as a *Block* variable for that statement, isolating its meaning from any other **x** you have in your program, so it enables the chain rule. For example:

```
In[85]:= z=x^2;
D[Sin[z],{x,1}]
Out[86]= 2 x Cos[x^2]
```

See? That's perfect! But there is a price.

The price is that the symbols inside the derivative get evaluated as the derivative is taken, and that is spoiling your code.

Of course there are a lot of tricks to get around this. Some have already been mentioned. From my point of view, one clear way to undertand what is happening is:

```
f[x_] := x*Exp[t*x];
g[y_, m_] := D[f[x], {x, m}] /. x -> y;
{g[p, 2], g[0, 1]}
```

Out:

```
{2 E^(p t) t + E^(p t) p t^2, 1}
```

HTH!